# Scrollbar in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I want page to scroll up gently when modal opens opens. But it is not working as expected. Instead, the scrollbar is moving abruptly upward. Am I doing anything wrong here ?

```
ScrollingSteps() {
    console.log(window.pageYOffset);/* This is giving me 0, even when scroll 
    bar is not on the top. Why is it showing this strange behavior ? */
    if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
        clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }

    window.scroll(0, window.pageYOffset - 5);// It is showing abrupt change
    console.log(document.body.scrollTop,document.body.style.top)/*Even these 2 are 0 here. Don't understand why!*/
}


ScrollingToTop() {
    let myID = setInterval(this.ScrollingSteps.bind(this), 5);
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add code for the entire component?

Answer (score 2):

with `window.scrollTo` you can make use of `behavior` prop adn provide value `smooth`

```js
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: window.pageYOffset - 5,
  behavior: 'smooth',
})
```

see here for details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: thanks for your answer but by using behaviour props still, I'm seeings abrupt jump of scroll bar